# Difference between reverse algorithm and list::reverse

Tags: c++, stl

```
std::list<int> l{1,2,3};
std::reverse(l.begin(), l.end());  // 1
l.reverse(); // 2
```

I guess I should prefer `list::reverse()`. Just wondering if there is any difference between 1 and 2 in above code? e.g. performance?

Comment: If you're worried about performance, why not benchmark it? Create a list of a million items, and reverse it a million times, timing the whole reversion process. Do it for both functions, and see which is quickest.

Comment: well i gueass a timer and a quick benchmark whould solve your own question here. ahh @JoachimPileborg you beat me by 19s

Comment: Actually you should prefer `std::reverse` when coming from a refactoring perspective. If you ever change you `list` to some other container, there is a chance that it might not implement `reverse` itself, but that the `std::reverse` algorithm will still work.

Comment: @Timo: Then again, `std::list` should only have been used when its particular abilities were needed, which bars refactoring.

Comment: @MSalters It's the general advice I got when working with these constructs. However I agree that it doesn't happen often that you actually need to change the container type. One example I got was performance benchmarking. It's easier to compare `list` and `vector` when you only have to change the container type and not the functional code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `list::reverse` can rearrange the list by changing the internal pointers between the nodes. `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>` will move the values (which works even if the sequence is not a standard container).

In your specific case, using an `int` data type, it isn't that obvious if it is a win to move two pointers instead of swapping two `int`s. You might want to run some benchmarks if it is important.